# running a feature twice

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

Is it possible to run a specflow feature twice but with two different entry points?

```
Feature: Blah.
 Scenario: Get Call.
 Given I have enpoint.
 And I create get call. 
 Then I should get my results.
```

I want to be able to run the same feature twice pointing to 2 different endpoints. What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Use a scenario outline. You can use data-driven tests to pass a different set of parameters for each test scenario: http://specflow.org/documentation/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow/

Answer (score 2):

You can use scenario outline:

> Scenario outlines can be used to define data-driven acceptance tests.
>   They can be also seen as scenario templates. The scenario outline
>   always consists of a scenario template specification (a scenario with
>   data placeholders using the '`<placeholder>`' syntax) and a set of
>   examples that provide values for the placeholders.

In your particular case:

```
Scenario Outline: getting call
 Given I have <enpoint>.    
 And I create get call. 
 Then I should get my results.

 Examples:
   | endpoint |
   |  fooUrl  |
   |  barUrl  |
```

Further reading: [Scenario Outlines](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines)

Comment: Thanks Sergey maybe I didn't explain enough. We already have a set of features with multiple scenarios outlines. But now they want to run the set of features twice pointing to two different locations.  So I was wondering if there is a way to run an scenario twice with a conditional of some sort.

Comment: @AntonioChiong sorry, I still don't get you. Scenario outline will generate two scenarios with corresponding parameters - that is exactly what you have described in comment '*run an scenario twice with a conditional of some sort*'